# Why I can't see Top bar, after navigationcontroller go back programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have navigation controller with rootViewController and childViewController.
When I start my app I see Top Bar on my rootViewController. Then I go to childViewController trough segue and than try to return to rootViewController

```
 @IBAction func exitButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
         navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
```

but it is start without Top Bar.
I go back programmatically, because on my childViewController Top Bar is hidden.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a boolean value that can solve what you need:
       `self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true`

Set it to true or false when you need to.